# How is "appeal" interpreted in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I have been confused with this sentence for about an hour and I am not able to get what the author means by "appeal", doubting there might even be a grammatical mistake:

> Therefore, ANN models cannot be compared to
>   process-based models or **appeal** to process hydrologists without being able to
>   predict more than one output simultaneously.

It is about hydroinformatics and a books.google.com link to the page I encountered the sentence is available [here](http://bit.ly/1HLC5Jq), with the sentence I addressed being in the last paragraph of page 391.

Answer (score 2):

Appeal has several meanings (10 according to OED).

The most likely meaning here is 'to be attractive' to Process Hydrologists. The attractiveness depends on whether it can 'predict more than one output simultaneously'.

Comment: @whanroft you mean *cannot* also refers to *appeal*?

Answer (score 1):

> Therefore, ANN models cannot be compared to process-based models or appeal to process hydrologists, without being able to predict more than one output simultaneously.

Adding a comma after "hydrologists" helps. Then substitute the "or" phrases:

> Therefore, ANN models cannot **be compared to process-based models** without being able to predict more than one output simultaneously.

and

> Therefore, ANN models cannot **appeal to process hydrologists** without being able to predict more than one output simultaneously.

As I read it, the use of "without" means *cannot* applies to both phrases. If you leave it out, the second statement does not make sense in context.

Comment: You mean once *without* is left out, *cannot* does not apply to both?

Comment: I think the without clause is a red herring. You can drop it entirely without changing the meaning. "It cannot be compared to A or appeal to B." doesn't need a "without" to make "cannot" apply to both "be compared to" and "appeal to". "It cannot appeal to B or be compared to A." means the same thing.